# SDK install procedure in raspberry pi3 for image processing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, openalpr

I want to install SDK for Automatic License Plate Recognition on Raspberry Pi 3.
I have searched with Google but didn't find any instruction on how to install SDK for alpr.
Can anyone please show the procedure to install SDK on Raspberry Pi 3 for Automatic license plate recognition?

Answer (score 1):

On Raspberry Pi 3 there are is no binary distribution for OpenALPR as far as I know. Hence, you need to build the library yourself. The openalpr project [README](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr) contains fairly detailed build instructions for various platforms - Ubuntu Linux is the closest I'd say. There is also a blog article ([Part 1](https://blog.vinczejanos.info/2016/08/31/install-openalpr-on-raspberry-pi-3/) and [Part 2](https://blog.vinczejanos.info/2017/05/01/install-openalpr-on-raspberry-pi-3-part-2/)) which describes the build on Raspberry 3 in detail, but part 1 is dated from 2016 and part 2 is dated 2017. So, it may be outdated. Another option may be to use Docker on Raspberry.

Another option is to the [OpenALPR Cloud API](https://www.openalpr.com/cloud-api.html). This way, the software on the raspberry will perform REST requests to let the cloud service perform the recognition. You can create a free account with a rate limit of 2000 recognitions per month. There is a Node-RED plugin which can be used to realize the REST client and the processing chain. There is a nice [A-Z tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/car-plate-recognition-system-with-raspberry-pi-and-node-red/) for getting things setup on Raspberry Pi 3 including all the hardware setup.

It should also be noted there is a commercial version of OpenALPR referred to as [Commercial SDK](http://doc.openalpr.com/sdk.html). The documentation also included information how to obtain and install the package.

Comment: Sir don't take silly, is it possible to install Local SDK for alpr in raspberry-pi 3

Comment: The first part of my answer provides information about installing the OpenALPR library and its dependencies (OpenCV, Leptonica, Tesseract). I think that is the SDK.

Comment: Well, there is also a commercial SDK and I added a short info about this to my post. To get the full picture please also have a look at http://doc.openalpr.com/

Comment: sorry, i'm using ONVIF in python and someone said that Local SDK will have all the tools for alpr.

Comment: Considering the low CPU and memory profile of the Raspberry Pi 3 you're perhaps better off with Cloud API solution.

Comment: memory is not a issue. Please can you suggest for "Local SDK".

Comment: Also have a look at the "On-Premises ALPR" section of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

DTK LPR SDK support Raspberry Pi 3/4.
http://dtksoft.com/lprsdk
This SDK have linux arm64/armhf libraries what can be executed on rpi.